# restTemplate.exchange for GET method gives Server Error 500

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4, spring-restcontroller

My rest Controller Code

Controller Code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/webphone")
@Component("WebphoneController")
@Service
public class WebphoneController {

Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebphoneController.class);

@Autowired
private WebphoneService webphoneService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/findUsers", 
        method = { RequestMethod.GET },  
        consumes = "application/json", 
        produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> findUsers(
        @RequestBody(required=true)  WebphoneFilter webphoneFilter,
        @RequestBody(required=false)  Paging paging
        ) {
```

Unit test Code:

```
@Test
public void webophoneController_whenGivenWebphoneFilter_shouldReturnListOfUsers() throws URISyntaxException {

    final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/webphone/findUsers";
    WebphoneFilter filter = new WebphoneFilter();
    filter.setOrgLeaderId("jn1488");

    URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);
    /*String requestJson = Util.Object2Json(filter);
    System.out.println(requestJson);
    */
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<>(filter,headers);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity answer = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, List.class);
    System.out.println("webophoneController_whenGivenWebphoneFilter_shouldReturnListOfUsers>>>>"+ answer);
    Assert.assertEquals("No service found for the URL", answer);
}
```

I get org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null

Comment: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97)
DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:775)
RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:728)
RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:702)
RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:619)
Tests.webophoneController_whenGivenWebphoneFilter_shouldReturnListOfUsers(WebphoneControllerTests.java:76)

Comment: fails on  call ResponseEntity answer = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, List.class);

Comment: Need a stack-trace from Web Application to understand what is happening. 500 error usually occurs due to unhandled exception in web-application.

Comment: You have a lot of redundant annotations. `@RestController` is a `@Component`, `@Service` is a `@Component`. `@RestController` usually not a `@Service`. You can leave only two annotation on WebphoneController: `@RestController("WebphoneController")` and `@RequestMapping("/webphone")`. Another problems are two `@RequestBody` annotation in one method and GET-request with body - usually do not do that.

Comment: @AnatolySamoylenko I made following change but still get a 500 as earlier.

Comment: You wrote an exception stack from Test. But the exception stack-trace from Web Application is needed to understand what is happening. Look in the application logs or application console. 500 error usually occurs due to unhandled exception in web-application.

Comment: Found 2 things today. 
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
gave better logs.       
Found that RequestBody for GET request is not good. I moved the request to POST and it worked like a charm Thanks, All.

Answer (score 0):

Controller Code:

```
@RestController("WebphoneController")
@RequestMapping("/webphone")
public class WebphoneController {

Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebphoneController.class);

@Autowired
private WebphoneService webphoneService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/findUsers", 
        method = { RequestMethod.GET },  
        consumes = "application/json", 
        produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> findUsers(
        @RequestBody(required=true)  WebphoneFilter webphoneFilter,
        @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false, defaultValue = "10000")  int pageSize
        ) {
    }
}
```

Unit Test Code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MicroUiApplication.class, CommonConfiguration.class, WebMvcConfig.class}, webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)    
@TestPropertySource(locations= "classpath:application.properties")
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class WebphoneControllerTests {

@LocalServerPort
int randomServerPort;

@Test
public void webophoneController_whenGivenWebphoneFilter_shouldReturnListOfUsers() throws URISyntaxException {

    final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/webphone/findUsers";
    WebphoneFilter filter = new WebphoneFilter();
    filter.setOrgLeaderId("jn1488");

    URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);
    /*String requestJson = Util.Object2Json(filter);
    System.out.println(requestJson);
    */
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<>(filter,headers);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity answer = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, List.class);
    System.out.println("webophoneController_whenGivenWebphoneFilter_shouldReturnListOfUsers>>>>"+ answer);
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.SC_OK, answer.getStatusCode());
  }
}
```